# Set nano as a default editor over Vim

Tags: vim, shell, nano

Every time I login to ssh terminal to edit files I execute the command

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

How Could I set nano as default editor so I shouldn't execute this command anymore

Comment: Has been answered dozens of times: https://www.google.com/search?q=export+editor+default

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Remove the spaces around the `=`; that syntax is invalid.
2. Put the line into `~/.bashrc` (assuming you use the Bash shell).